# Using tabs alone for indentation in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ide, indentation

I love Emacs but don't like how it does indentation: either an uncontrollable mix of tabs-and-spaces or just spaces (`(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)`).

I want Emacs to do do indentation:

1. With tabs alone.
2. Do the indentation to a fixed number of places (not 6 sometimes, 8 other times and 4 in some other places).
3. Be able to set one level of indentation as being equal to 4 (or 2) spaces.
4. If I change the value of the tab stop, all newly-opened or reloaded files should use the new value (or can this change be affected only by re-starting Emacs?)

Is all of the above possible? Some settings in `.emacs` or a package?

Most IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) offer the above.

Comment: I only use spaces so I dont have answere to your question. But did you see this page.? http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs

Comment: @kindahero the link you gave pretty much answers all my questions (and them some!). Could I trouble you to add that link as an answer so I could mark it as the accepted one & give you credit for your effort? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[smart tabs](http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs) would insert tabs and spaces contextually.

Personally I only use spaces for both indentation and alignment (at least for my own projects). [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabsAreEvil) is another article on emacswiki I found very useful about the topic

Comment: for those looking to use this in spacemacs, curtmack has made a start (https://github.com/curtmack/spacemacs-conf/tree/master/private/local/smart-tabs) - the pull request needs some bug fixes before merging (https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/6467)

Answer (score 3):

For C/C++/Java, you could try adding to your mode hook an identical tab-width, indent-level and c-basic-offet:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (setq c-indent-level 3
    c-brace-offset -3)
  (setq c-basic-offset 3)
  (setq-default tab-width 3)
  (setq tab-width 3))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

This makes it so when you're in cc-mode, tabs and indenting are equal so emacs will always choose tabs over spaces. See also [Indenting C](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC)

The `tab-width` can be set elsewhere and you can apply it to other modes in conjunction with indent length variables like [python's **python-indent**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingPython).

---

Edit:

Actually, it looks like kindahero's link pretty much does this: http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs

Comment: This is useful code, especially for someone — like me — who doesn't know elisp. Thanks, but as you yourself pointed out, @kindahero's link pretty much covers everything on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

I use tabs for indentation. But when someone else using a different editor, they could see that the indentation is gone. So, you can select the piece of code that you indented using tabs and run "M-x untabify". This replaces the tabs with white space, so the first said issue won't be there for the users using a different editor.